# Uninitialised Enum in C

Tags: c

I have the unfortunate task of bringing some code written in C into C++.

I've come across an uninitialised enum in a struct with the following form.

```
enum theEnum {
  A = 1,
  B = 2,
  C = 3,
}

struct theCStruct{
  enum theEnum enuminstance;
}

theCStruct structInstance;
```

I know that in C++ this would be undefined, but as I'm finding out uninitialised variables in C structs default to 0 (at least for ints) rather than undefined.

In this case what will the default value of the enum be in C?

Comment: `undefined`, or `unspecified`? I think the value would be indeterminate,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> uninitialised variables in C structs default to 0 (at least for ints)
>   rather than undefined.

That is a myth, unless the `struct` instance has `static` or `_Thread_local` storage duration or is at global scope.

The two languages are identical in this respect.

As a rule of thumb, don't *port*, but *interop*. C has an extremely good API on common operating systems.

Comment: The C that I have been given does not have `static` or `_Thread_local` storage and is at the scope of a function. It is however initialised with designated initializer syntax for 75% of the variables. It is the other 25% that are left untouched. Would you expect these to exhibit undefined behavior? Unfortunately I'm working with a proprietary RTOS, but will explore better C APIs

Comment: @RoryHughes: There are some exceptions, but in general you need to initialise all automatic variables prior to reading them.

Comment: There is not such thing as "exhibiting undefined behaviour".

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Absolutely.